Solving $\int\frac{1+\ln x}{3+x\ln x}dx$
I try to solve $\int\frac{1+\ln x}{3+x\ln x}dx$ in this manner:
$
\int\frac{1+\ln x}{3+x\ln x}dx = \int\frac{1}{3+x\ln x}dx + \int\frac{\ln x}{3+x\ln x}dx
$
Then we know answer of $\int\frac{\ln x}{3+x\ln x}dx = \ln|3+\ln|x|| + c$
But what about $\int\frac{1}{3+x\ln x}dx$ ?  I know $\int\frac{1}{x\ln x}dx = \ln|\ln x|+c$. But we should solve $3+$ .

I think you should double check your derivative of $x\ln x$.

@Mike Oh you right mike! Thank you.

Also, notice that the third line of your integration was wrong.

@Morten I get it after your reply

$\int_{} \frac{1+\ln x}{3+x\ln x}dx=\int_{} \frac{1}{3+x\ln x}d(3+x \ln x)$
Just notice that the derivative of $x \ln x $ is $1+\ln x$.

Thank you very much! Unfortunately I spent more than 1 hours for this very simple big mistake.

@alirezaarzehgar Before doing problems like this one, try to observe the relation between the numerator and denominator, that helps.

I will definitely pay attention to this point.
